# Kreysig's Picard's Existence and Uniqueness Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

What does the $|f(t,x)|\leq c$ mean geometrically?
Also, $f$ satisfies Lipschitz condition on $R$ with respect second argument, what does it mean also? [image]

Comment: $|f(t,x)| \leq c$ means this function is bounded  $\forall (t,x) \in $ region $R$

Comment: i mean, what does that $c$ mean? A constant?

Comment: yes it is a constant

Comment: i think they are using property of continous function i.e a continous function on a closed interval is bounded.Here in your theorem closed interval is replaced with closed Rectangle.

Comment: But, I saw the next page, they mention $c$ as a slope.